# Detect when keyboard has finished changing size and all subviews are positioned

Tags: ios, ios8, keyboard, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

In my custom keyboard I add a constraint in `updateConstraints` that increases the height of the keyboard. This causes the subviews to adjust (also using Auto Layout) to the new size. I need to call a function when the layout has finished adjusting its size and all subviews have been positioned (to store the positions of some of the new elements to be used later, and manually update some elements in response to this new layout). This code needs to be triggered again when the size has changed and elements repositioned, for example after rotating the device. What function I should use to run that code?

`viewDidAppear` is only called once, and that's too early because the keyboard hasn't adjusted in size at that time.

`updateViewConstraints` doesn't work because the subviews haven't been laid out in response to the updated constraint yet. I tried calling `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` then `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in an attempt to force the update to occur before calling my function, but that didn't make a difference - it still runs the function before the keyboard finished laying out subviews.

I tried `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and while it is called after views have settled, the problem is this function is called a million times while scrolling the collection view in the keyboard. I can't call that function when scrolling, I can only call it a single time after the keyboard size has changed and views have settled into position.

I thought about calling it in `viewDidAppear` after a delay, then also in a rotation method such as `viewWillTransitionToSize` after another delay, but this would be very fragile. I could increase the delay to make it less fragile, but I want to ensure this method is called as early as possible to ensure everything is updated as soon as possible.

Comment: Does [keyboardDidShow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardDidShowNotification) Notification not work

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when I worked on this problem pre-iOS 8.3, there are no silver bullets for this. I don't know precisely what your needs are for what you're doing, but here are a number of possible solutions that I've tried, maybe they'll be helpful to you:

First; assume that your keyboard will eventually be updated to your "desired" size and perform your layout based on that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You do the layout for sizing once, and then never do it again, except if you detect that you've changed orientation. This has the drawbacks that a) for the time before your height constraint is updated, your keyboard will only partially appear on screen, b) that in some cases the height constraint will not be respected and you'll be left with a misshapen keyboard (you can solve this with the timer, but as you observed it's pretty fragile), and c) that it will be difficult to make this work properly in "scaled-for-retina" apps on iPhone 6/6+.

Second; Detect when the height of your `UIInputView` has changed, and pass that info on to your collection view, so it only relayouts things when this occurs. In my experience this will probably happen only two more times than is necessary.

Third; Detect when the collectionview is scrolling (you can sign up for the callbacks from the scrollview) and don't do your expensive layouting operations while this is occurring. This is also very fragile.

Whatever you do, be sure to test what happens when you're in scaled-for-retina apps, when the user enters a password field while your layout operations that are stateful are occurring, what happens if the user closes the keyboard while you're doing things, what happens if the user closes the keyboard and reopens it before your keyboard UI is deallocated and is therefore recycled (when it slides up animated instead of popping, generally), etc. You can end up with invalid state that'll screw up future operations, or a reference cycle and/or strong reference to your keyboard UI from your timer if you're not careful.

In the case of storing element positions, again, I don't know what you're doing, but it would probably be better to just read these properties directly than to store them. More state is more potential problems.

A final comment -- I haven't tested this myself, but some people have reported that autolayout in third party keyboards is really slow -- you seem to be implying that you use it to lay out views -- I would profile to see if it's really your code that's causing your problem, which I assume is unacceptably long times for your keyboard to pop.

I hope this is helpful.